# Java RMI 'java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1;'

Tags: java, rmi, hosts, policyfiles

I'm attempting to setup a test application using the java RMI to achieve basic communication and I'm having issues getting it to operate over LAN. I saw a thread with the same error as me but I couldn't find a solution for my issue in there. In the previous thread they were referring to the hosts file being incorrect I will include mine for clarity, here is my code:

https://github.com/MAWoodMain/RMI-LAN/tree/master/src

and my hosts file includes the following lines:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

127.0.0.1       rpi-tank
```

The full error is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:130)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:194)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:148)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.poke(Unknown Source)
    at RPI.<init>(RPI.java:21)
    at RPI.main(RPI.java:30)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Just as in the other thread, your hosts file is incorrect.

Comment: @EJP what specifically can I do to fix it?

Comment: Provide a correct IP address for `rpi-tank` that isn't `127.0.0.1`.